# envar datos de formulario a php a traves de ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

al enviar los datos de un formulario por ajax a php. la variable a la muestra bien sin embargo la variable me muestra Notice: Undefined index: usuario

aqui está en formulario y la llamada ajax

```js
 $('#formularioRegistro').submit(function(event) {
    var parametros = $(this).serialize();
    var funcion = "inserta";
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "cone.php",
      data: { parametros, funcion },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#resultado').html(data);
      }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" id="formularioRegistro" name="formularioRegistro" method="post">
    <div class="col l6 m6 s12">
      <div class="input-field">
        <i class="fas fa-user prefix"></i>
        <input class="validate" type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" required>
        <label for="usuario">Usuario</label>
        <span class="helper-text" data-error="Sin espacios vacíos."></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  <center>
    <div class="row" id="resultado">
      <button type="submit"
              class="col s12 btn btn-large waves-effect light-blue darken-4">Registrarse
      </button>
    </div>
  </center>
</form>
```

y en el archivo php

```
echo $a = $_POST['funcion']; echo $b = $_POST['usuario'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que estás mandando mal los datos, prueba lo siguiente:

```
$('#formularioRegistro').submit(function(event) {
    var parametros = $(this).serialize() + '&funcion=inserta';
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "cone.php",
      data: parametros,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#resultado').html(data);
      }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
```

Si mal no recuerdo serialize ya incluye los Brackets del objeto. Dime si tienes dudas.